# Extract a sample file from mp3 file using PHP

Tags: php, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically trimming a mp3 in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404969/automatically-trimming-a-mp3-in-php)

Hi

I am working on a project for a client that will involve the selling of mp3's.

The client would like to be able to simply upload the mp3 and the system will automatically generate a sample of the first 30 seconds of the full mp3.

Can this be done via code?

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Comment: yeah I'll try the class mentioned in the quesiton. I'll report if it works :)

Comment: the class pointed out in the possible duplicate worked great :)

Comment: you can use  PHP MP3 CLASS. I used that only.

Comment: I have code in that you can extract initial 30 seconds of mp3.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux as your production platform you might have to consider using approaches from
http://www.go2linux.org/trim-cut-join-split-mp3-files-with-linux

Just call these comnmands from php via `system` or `exec` functions

Comment: This looks interesting too ... the class suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404969/automatically-trimming-a-mp3-in-php seems to do the job fine. Thanks anyways will keep this in mind just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no...

Yes : Php could call a simple binary which do the job (params included) with `exec()` or `passthru()`.

And No : php isn't able (whitout extension) to process mp3 files. I had the same problem with videos: i used ffmpeg (Linux command line processing program for videos) launched thru php in order to generate 30sec samples and screenshots.

Comment: I guess you can always program mp3 splitter in pure PHP so it can be used without additional extensions, but this will cost a lot of time and efforts ;)